# How to collect hardware event counts with perf stat on KVM host/guest?

Tags: kvm, perf

On a 6.4 host (2.6.32-358) on SandyBridge, I am trying to collect hardware event counts for guest activity with perf stat. Although virt-top reports healthy activity in the guests, I get the following with the ":G" modifier

```
 # perf stat -e cycles:G sleep 10
```

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 10':

```
             0 cycles:G                  #    0.000 GHz
```

I tried collecting inside the guest, but get the following:

```
 # perf stat -e cycles -A -a sleep 1

Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

CPU0       < not supported> cycles
```

I see that there is a perf kvm, but this only has top/record/report and seems to be intended for profiling an application using sampling, not collecting hardware counts.

On the host, how do I get perf stat to count the guest activity; and on the guest, what is needed to expose hardware event counting to perf stat?